# Subprocess call stopping asynchronously-executed Python parent process

Tags: python, bash, ffmpeg, python-2.6

The following shell session demonstrates the behavior I am seeing:

```
[user@compname python-test]$ cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
from time import sleep
proc = subprocess.Popen("ffmpeg", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
print "Starting process: " + str(proc)
status = proc.poll()
while status is None:
    print "Process still running."
    sleep(0.01)
    status = proc.poll()
print "Status: " + str(status)
[user@compname python-test]$ python test.py
Starting process: <subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f2893f27150>
Process still running.
Process still running.
Status: 1
[user@compname python-test]$ python test.py &
[4] 6976
[user@compname python-test]$ Starting process: <subprocess.Popen object at 0x7ffa0ea82150>
Process still running.
Process still running.
[4]+  Stopped                 python test.py
[user@compname python-test]$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4684 pts/101  00:00:00 python
 4685 pts/101  00:00:00 ffmpeg
 7183 pts/101  00:00:00 ps
14385 pts/101  00:00:00 bash
```

As you can see, when the simple test Python program is run normally, it completes successfully.  When it is run asynchronously (using `&`), the Python process is stopped as soon as the subprocess call is complete (and `poll()` would return a non-`None` value).

1. The same behavior occurs when using `Popen.wait()`
2. The behavior is unique to `ffmpeg`.
3. Both the Python process and `ffmpeg` are ending up stopped, as seen in the call to `ps`.

Can someone help me detangle this behavior?  I don't see anything in the documentation for the `subprocess` module, bash's `&` operator, or `ffmpeg` that would explain this.

The Python version is 2.6.6, bash is GNU bash version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu), ffmpeg is version 3.0.1-static.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that `ffmpeg` blocks itself when run asynchronously. A mailing list revealed that using `nohup` avoids the problem. See [here](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2011-June/001277.html) for those interested.

Answer (score 1):

Does the same thing occur when shell=False? You'll have to point to the direct path of the executable when using shell=False.

Comment: Yes, precisely the same behavior; the synchronous task completes successfully, the asynchronous task is stopped along with the child ffmpeg process.

Comment: What about using `proc.communicate()` instead of `proc.poll()`? Remove the while loop and set `status = proc.communicate()` instead, and get the return code with `proc.returncode`. Note that `communicate()` is blocking.

Comment: Yup, I've also tried `communicate()`; same behavior.

Comment: I've discovered that `ffmpeg` blocks itself when run asynchronously. A mailing list revealed that using `nohup` avoids the problem. See [here](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2011-June/001277.html) for those interested.  If anyone has further insight about the possible cause, I'd be interested to know.